# Can a JTAG debugger access CORTEXM4 processor registers like DHCSR to enable Reset Vector Catch while the processor is in reset state.?

Tags: arm, reset, cpu-registers, cortex-m, jtag

I wanted to know if a JTAG debugger can access debug enabling registers of CORTEXM4 like DHCSR while the Power on reset and System reset has been asserted.
Or do we deassert only the Power On Reset and access the registers with System Reset asserted?

If I want the processor to get into debug mode out of reset, the debugger will have to set the DHCSR.C_DEBUGEN bit to 1. Can this register be accessed when the Power on Reset and System reset has been asserted?

Just needed information on the reset sequence for an external JTAG to program the CPU to get into debug mode right after all the resets have been deasserted.

Comment: jtag can halt and release reset on cortex-ms, if that is the register in question, dont know have you looked at openocd.  Are you trying to roll your own jtag tools?   look at the existing open source ones for a reference.

Comment: well swd that is not jtag.